# jQuery datepicker not selectable anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jQuery datepicker that used to be working very well. However, since yesterday, I must have changed something. When I hover over the calendar, nothing happens. When I click on the calendar, nothing works. But, I am able to change the behaviour of the calendar via code. As you can see, I was able to remove the prev and next buttons in the first calendar. Is there anything I forgot to check? Why can I not select any date of the calendar anymore? Any hint is appreciated. Btw, I checked the code on JSFiddle, and there it is working :(

This is my **JavaScript**:

```
$(function() {
    var startDate;
    var endDate;

var selectCurrentWeek = function() {

    window.setTimeout(function () {
          $('#datepicker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day tr').addClass('ui-state-hover');
          $('#datepicker').find('.ui-datepicker-next').remove();
          $('#datepicker').find('.ui-datepicker-prev').remove();
    }, 1);
}

$('#datepicker').datepicker( {
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: false,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
        endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
        $('#calendar').weekCalendar('gotoWeek', date);
        selectCurrentWeek();
    },
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var cssClass = '';
        if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
            cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
        return [true, cssClass];
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        selectCurrentWeek();
    }
});

$('#datepicker' ).datepicker( "option", $.datepicker.regional[ 'de' ] );
$('#datepicker').find('.ui-datepicker-next').remove();
$('#datepicker').find('.ui-datepicker-prev').remove();
$('#datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
$('#datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });


    // handling datepicker classes
    var startDate;
    var endDate;

    var selectCurrentWeek_next = function() {

        window.setTimeout(function () {
        }, 1);
    }

    $('#datepicker_next_month').datepicker( {
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $('#calendar').weekCalendar('gotoWeek', date);
            selectCurrentWeek_next();
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek_next();
        }
    });

    $('#datepicker_next_month' ).datepicker( "option", $.datepicker.regional[ 'de' ] );
    $('#datepicker_next_month' ).datepicker().datepicker('setDate','+1m');
    $('#datepicker_next_month .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    $('#datepicker_next_month .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
});
```

This is the relevant **HTML** part:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<div id="datepicker_next_month"></div>
```

These are the scripts I import:

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='libs/jquery-1.4.4.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='libs/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='libs/jquery-ui-i18n.js'></script>
```

Here is an image of the calendar:

[image]

Comment: Did your browser upgrade?

Comment: Well probably, but it is not working in Chrome, Safari or Firefox.

Comment: did you upgraded your jquery version.. i see you are using.. jquery-1.4.4.min.js.. have you upgraded it to latest version 1.9.1

Comment: No I did not upgrade the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I used Google Chroms Element inspector and discovered, that another div was overlaying the datepicker divs. After fixing that problem, everything works again :)